# Qt doesn't recognize other sub-projects

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmake, subdirectory

I'm currently working with QT-Creator on MacOS and I'm stuck a little bit at 2 points at the moment. I've got a main-project and two sub-projects. So far this is working fine.

The .pro file of the main project looks like this:

```
//...
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += Proj1
SUBDIRS += Proj2
```

The `Proj1.pro` file looks like this:

```
TARGET = Proj1
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += someclass1.cpp
HEADERS += someclass1.h
```

The `Proj2.pro` looks similar except the SOURCES and HEADERS part:

```
//...
SOURCES += someclass2.cpp main.cpp
HEADERS += someclass2.h
```

---

**Now to the interesting part**:

My `someclass1.cpp` contains a global variable and looks like this:

```
#include "someclass1.h"
int g_something = 18;
SomeClass1::SomeClass1() {}
```

My `someclass2.cpp` tries to access that global variable via the keyword `extern`:

```
#include "someclass2.h"
#include "../Proj1/someclass1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
extern int g_something;
SomeClass2::SomeClass2() {
    printf("g_something: %d\n", g_something);
}
```

---

When i'm trying to compile i receive 2 errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_g_something", referenced from:
        SomeClass2::SomeClass2() in someclass2.o ...
```

and

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_main", referenced from:
        start in crt1.10.6.o
```

---

- I know the first error comes from using `g_something` from `someclass1` without properly linking `Proj1` to `Proj2` but **I don't know how to tell the linker that i use that other subproject**
- I guess the second error is there because i don't have a main-method defined in project `Proj1`, but I don't know what to do so there's no main method expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you try to compile two independent applications Proj1 and Proj2. They doesn't have any kind of linkage between each other. They both should have `main(...)` function. And of course you can't declare `extern` var in that case. If you want create one application, then on of your subprojects should be a library and other subproject should link with it. Then you can use external declaration.

At `Proj2.pro` declare `TEMPLATE = lib`. And at Proj1 add linkage with this lib like `LIBS += -lProj2`. Of course you should add path to `libproj2` location.

Answer (score 1):

your proj1 should be `lib`, not `app`, if you want to use `extern`.
and your main project should add `ordered`